# Python Dash DataTable not showing rows

Tags: python, datatable, plotly-dash

I am trying to display a Dash DataTable but only the column titles are displayed. I've double checked everything but a the row with 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' is not displaying.
Also if I set `data=[]` and I try to access it from a Callback, it will say that the data is `None`.

```
dash_table.DataTable(
    id='orders_table',
    columns=[
        {'name': 'Ticker', 'id': 'orders_table_ticker'},
        {'name': 'Date', 'id': 'orders_table_date'},
        {'name': 'Type', 'id': 'orders_table_type'},
        {'name': 'Repeat every x days', 'id': 'orders_table_repeat'}],
    data=[{
        'orders_table_ticker':'a',
        'orders_table_date':'b',
        'orders_table_type':'c',
        'orders_table_repeat':'d'}],
    row_deletable=True
)
```

This is the result

[image: result]

Comment: Running your code works perfectly for me, it could potentially be a version problem, so try and upgrade to the newest version of dash and dash_table.

Comment: Thank you for your help @AS11. It was my callback function clearing the table (even without being called).